# Twig : translation for element of array displayed via split

Tags: arrays, split, translation, twig

Let's say I have this kind of arrays :

```
<?php
$monsterOne['statistics'] = array('attack' => 15, 'defense' => 20, 'speed' => 5);
$monsterTwo['statistics'] = array('attack' => 10, 'defense' => 0, 'speed' => 7);
```

**And I want to display, via twig :**

```
monsterOne : 15 en Attaque, 20 en Défense, 5 en Vitesse
monsterTwo : 10 en Attaque, 7 en Vitesse
```

How can I achieve this ?

I tried this, and it worked, **but the commas between each statistic are not present.**

```
{% if statistics.attack is defined %} {{statistics.attack}} {{"en Attaque" | trans}} {% endif %}
{% if statistics.defense is defined %} {{statistics.defense}} {{"en Défense" | trans}} {% endif %}
{% if statistics.escape is defined %} {{statistics.escape}} {{"en Vitesse" | trans}} {% endif %}
```

I think that I should use something like this, but I don't know how to put the translation inside :

```
{{ statistics|join(', ') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The trick was to parse the `array` via a `loop` and use `loop.last` :

```
    {% for statistic, value in statistics %}
        {% if statistic == 'attack' %} {{ value }} {{ 'en Attaque' | trans }}{% endif %}
        {% if statistic == 'defense' %} {{ value }} {{ 'en Defense' | trans }}{% endif %}
        {% if statistic == 'speed' %} {{ value }} {{ 'en Vitesse' | trans }}{% endif %}
        {% if loop.last == false %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}">
```